# Android 15 second long click with ACTION_UP always called upon release

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, touch-event, long-press

I am pulling my hair out trying to find a reliable way to consistently allow a user to long press on a gridview item for up to 15 seconds and ALWAYS ALWAYS receive a ACTION_UP when the users finger is released. I also would like to allow unlimited movement once a long press is detected NOTHING besides a finger being lifted should interrupt this process.

Some additional info this is all inside of a gridview which is inside of a pager , but ik what i want to do is possible bc ik of other apps that do such a thing flawlessly

Here is my most recent attempt, but ive tried dozens:

```
public class recordVideo implements OnLongClickListener,OnTouchListener {
    private int position;
    private String clicked_uid;
    public recordVideo(int position){
        this.position=position;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v){
        //do things
        // Do something when your hold starts here.
        isSpeakButtonLongPressed = true;
        Log.i("START_RECORD","longClick");
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View pView, MotionEvent pEvent) {
        pView.onTouchEvent(pEvent);


        if (pEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            Log.i("START","video");

        }
        // We're only interested in when the button is released.
        if (pEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // We're only interested in anything if our speak button is currently pressed.

            Log.i("STOP_RECORD","video");
            if (isSpeakButtonLongPressed) {
                // Do something when the button is released.
                isSpeakButtonLongPressed = false;
               // Log.i("STOP_RECORD","video");
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Please try returning false in your onLongClick and keep onTouch the same, or if that doesn't work, still return true in onLongClick, but return false in onTouch.

Comment: not much luck , not consistent . I get the feeling the issues relate to either the scroll of the grid or the viewpager taking over the touchEvent. I really dont care how much movement there is once a grid item is long pressed i want to freeze out any other possible touchevent until a  ACTION_UP is received from my grid item

Comment: not sure if that would make it easier or harder but it has to be possible , snapchat and taptalk both do something like this for different reasons but same code should be required